# How to Modify Find/Replace to refer to one cell only

Tags: vba, replace, find

I have the Find/Replace code below which uses the keyword "Cells", but the result is in changing everything in the sheet.  I have not been able to figure out how to make it refer to ONLY one cell.

```
     fnd = " himself "
     rplc = " herself "

     'Perform the Find/Replace All
     sht.Cells.Replace What:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
     LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, _
     SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I need to refer to change only one cell. It changes everything.

Comment: `Sht.Range(“A1”).Replace` will do (this looks in cell A1 of course). This can also be modified to by more dynamic by using `Sht.Cells(1, 1).Replace` where the column or row number can be replaced with any *numeric* variable

Answer (score 1):

Use this:
 Change A1 to your respective cell

```
 fnd = " himself "
 rplc = " herself "

 'Perform the Find/Replace All
 sht.Range("A1").Replace What:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
 LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, _
 SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```